# A simple-looking inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality

Assume that $L$ is a self-adjoint unbounded operator with domain $D(L) \subset H$, for a Hilbert space $H$ of real-valued functions on a compact set in $\mathbb R^d$. Is it true, at this level of generality, that
$$\|L^{\alpha}u\| \leq \|Lu\|^{\alpha} \qquad \forall u \in D(L),\, \|u\|=1, \qquad \forall \alpha \in [0, 1]?$$

If $D(L)$ admits a complete orthonormal basis of $L$, which we denote $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$, we have the representation (writing $u_i = \langle u, e_i \rangle$):
$$ \| L^{\alpha} u \|^2 = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda^{2\alpha} u_i^2 =: \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n.$$
By Jensen's inequality,
$$
S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda^{2\alpha} u_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (\lambda_i^2)^{\alpha} u_i^2 + 0^{\alpha} \, \left(1 - \sum_{i=1}^n u_i^2\right) \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2 u_i^2 + 0 \left(1 - \sum_{i=1}^n u_i^2\right)\, \right)^{\alpha} \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_i^2 u_i^2 \right)^{\alpha} = \|Lu\|^2,
$$
and taking $n \to \infty$ we obtain the desired inequality.

Is this reasoning valid? And can something be said when $D(L)$ does not admit a basis of eigenfunctions of $L$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f : \mathbb R\to\mathbb C$ be measurable. For $u\in H$ define the Borel measure $\mu_u(A) = \|E(A)u\|^2$, where $E$ denotes the spectral measure of $L$. Then
$$
\operatorname{dom}f(L) = \{u\in H : f\in L^2(\mu_u)\}
$$
and $\|f(L)u\|^2 = \int |f|^2\,d\mu_u$ for $u\in\operatorname{dom}f(L)$.

In your case you have $f(x) = x^\alpha$. Let $u\in\operatorname{dom}L$. Then $\operatorname{id}\in L^2(\mu_u)$ and hence (since $\alpha\in [0,1]$)
$$
\int |x|^{2\alpha}\,d\mu_u\,\le\,\int |x|^2\,d\mu_u < \infty.
$$
That is, $u\in\operatorname{dom}L^\alpha$. We even have
$$
\|L^\alpha u\|^2 = \int |x|^{2\alpha}\,d\mu_u\,\le\,\left(\int |x|^2\,d\mu\right)^\alpha = \|Lu\|^{2\alpha},
$$
which follows from [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_and_probabilistic_form) in the concave case. Applying the square root yields your result.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear answer. Is the spectral measure guaranteed to exist?

Comment: Yes. Every normal operator (and so also every self-adjoint operator) has a unique spectral measure associated to it. Conversely, given a spectral measure $E$, then $L = \int z\,dE_z$ defines a normal operator. If you are content with my answer, then please check it.

Comment: Great, thank! :)

Comment: Would you recommend a particular reference to learn about this?

Comment: This is covered in many books. For example in Conway's "A course in functional analysis", I think.